# Issue using seq() to generate time series in R

Tags: r, seq

I want to create a time series from a start date&time (t1) to a finish date&time (t2) by 10 minute intervals.

the code below works fine for all other t2 times bar 23:50:00

```
library(chron)
t1 <- chron("1/1/2006", "00:00:00")
t2 <- chron("1/3/2006", "23:50:00")
deltat <- times("00:10:00")
tt <- seq(t1, t2, by = times("00:10:00"))
```

I have tried this code in Rstudio on both linux and windows platforms, as well as from terminal on linux, to no avail.

any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a floating point issue. To get around it, you could add an additional second to `t2`

```
t2 = chron("1/3/2006", "23:50:01")
seq(t1, t2, by = times("00:10:00"))
```

Search for floating point on stack overflow. In R, the classic example is

```
R> sqrt(2)^2 ==2
[1] FALSE
```